How to automatically input the password when it is prompt in console in java
I have a java program which execute a jar java -jar <path>/pass.jar through a Process command execution.
After execute this command it is prompt "Enter Password>" in console. When I enter password manually, it's work fine. But I want to enter this password automatically in the same program from a string 'mypass' which hold my password.
My main java program will execute in linux through a shell script so I can't give the password manually when it's prompt.
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class testtest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cmd = "java -jar C:\\A\\tmp\\linux\\pass.jar";
        
        try {
            String mypass= "mypass";
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            //After executing the command in console it is asking for password like 'Enter Password>'. 
            //This password I want to input automatically when it's prompt from mypass string.
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String s = "";
            while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (s.contains("XYZ: ")) {
                    System.out.println("S 3:" + s);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           
       }
}



What happens if you create a new process, get the process input stream, and then do exec(cmd);?
